# DirectShow graph not able to capture the frames from actual camera

Tags: directshow

I wrote an Directshow application for capturing the video frames from camera. My capture graph looks like the below mentioned graph :

```
SourceFilter   ------>   SampleGrabberFilter  -----------> NULLRenderer
```

My application is capable to capture the frames from several virtual cameras ( i.e. OBS, DroidCam ). InCase of Nikon web cam utility - It always shows me the default Nikon web cam utility frame. If I connect the Nikon camera with my system, then also it was showing me default web cam screen. If I select Nikon web cam utility as a source in some other application like OBS then OBS can capture actual frames.At that moment If I open my application and select Nikon web cam utility as source , my appliaction can't capture frames(It is expected as camera was used by OBS). If I change the source in OBS (Select any other source) at that time my application can render the actual captured frames.

It looks like, my application automatically not able to capture the frames from the device. If the capture frame is started by any other application and switch to my application, then only it can capture video frames from device.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sometimes the DirectShow filter graph doesn't run without a renderer to push the video to. Have you tried either having the capture filter render the preview pin or replace the NULLRenderer with a normal video renderer?

Comment: @Don Jordan : I found the reason. While I discovered the devices I was holding the COM objects of the source filters. I did not release those COM objects. When I selected Nikon camera's web cam utility that COM object was not updated with the current frames. I don't the logic behind the device driver. But I guess, as the COM object was held by my application that's why the driver did not capture the frames from the device. While I released all the COM objects, it worked.

Comment: Yes, that will do it. Once a video capture device has been instantiated, it can't be used by another thread. Not directly anyway. It's probably a bandwidth issue.